# Why is the main application thread the fastest?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I had created a file compressor with many loops. In order to prevent my Form from freezing, I decided to use a `BackgroundWorker`. As there were many loops one after another, it was slower. I then shifted from `BackgroundWorker` to `Thread`, tried to increase the `Priority` to `Highest`, but the problem still remained.

When I tried to run the program without any `Thread` or `BackgroundWorker`, it was much faster than any `Thread` or `BackgroundWorker`, even with Highest Priority and with Administrative Rights.

Why is this so?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to show what you have attempted to far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `You are doing something wrong then`... please update your post to include what you have tried.

Comment: So many things could affect your measurement of "speed".  When using threads other than the main UI thread, when and how did you update the UI with results?  Show us some code...

Comment: @Idle_Mind I used a timer, that was running at the point where my loop starts, and in the timer, I added a line "Me.Refresh()", which refreshes the form at that instant. So, I managed to see the progress and speed of it.

Comment: I am really looking for the answer.

Comment: Still need to see some code here to analyze, but Refresh()ing periodically is definitely going to slow the process down.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Okay, I will update the post with my code in next hour.

Comment: Threads are only useful if you are running CPU intensive operations for a considerable time per thread created.The cost of constructing a thread is enormous so unless there is significant computation performed by each thread then it's often the case that not using threads is faster.

Comment: You sound like you're doing a number things wrong. You really should provide a [mcve] for us to work with.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have over 7 Loops in my program, and they run without a delay, so I firstly thought that Threads are good for intense loops. But actually they are slow.

Comment: @SaumitraTopinkatti - Threads may be good for intense loops, but it depends on what you mean by "intense". Can you please post your code rather than asking us to comment on the unclear description in your question?